# I want to create a TFS checkin policy which enforces to keep the dll in the project folder before checking into TFS

Tags: tfs, policies

I want to create a TFS checkin policy which enforces to keep the core dll in the project folder before checking into TFS.

Comment: What do you mean "core" dll?  What is your solution/project structure?

Comment: Okay. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use NuGet for package management instead of checking in the dll files into project. You need to restore NuGet packages during TFS build process and the required packages will be downloaded.